# Comparing value from MySQL to an int in PHP doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to make my own website, from scratch, for a school project. It is going very well, and I got really far, but I encountered an issue, when comparing a variable to a number in a PHP script.

(I skipped alot of the code, which is not relevant, such as SQL connection etc)

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO members (points) VALUES ('800')";
```

this works fine, and the number gets inserted in to my SQL databse as "int(64)"

then i put the variable in to a session in a PHP script

```
$_SESSION['points'] = $points[0];
```

then i put it down to another PHP script

```
$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT points FROM members WHERE username = $uname");
$points = mysql_fetch_row($SQL);
```

still fine, when I check $points[0] it is still 800

but I can't compare it in a statement such as this

```
if ($Points[0] >= 400)
{echo "took it";
}
else {echo "didnt take it";
}
```

Any idea of what could be wrong? It is bigger, but the variable gets threated as if its lower or empty.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly typecasting $Points[0] as Int?

Comment: Well you have written `$Points` instead of `$points`.

Comment: Variable names in PHP are case sensitive. You should use if ($points[0] >= 400).

Comment: What does 'var_dump' output?

Comment: This might be one of the worst titles i've ever seen on this site.

Comment: Could be wrong because I'm not the best with SQL but doesn't `VALUES ('800')` turn the number into a string? It always has for me but I might have been dealing with a different issue. Just a thought...

Comment: you might have to convert $points into a int because mysql gives a string of 800 not int 800 eg `if((int)$points[0] >= 400)`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: BTW, `int(64)` is a nonsense data type for MySQL.  The number is the max length and an `INT` can only be 10 digits at most.  If you meant to have a 64-bit integer, you should use `BIGINT`, but you probably don't need it to be that big.

Comment: @Class PHP has loose data types.

Answer (score 1):

I'm taking a guess here, but I think you intend to compare `$_SESSION['points']` when you say *"then i put it down to another PHP script"*.

You need to update `$_SESSION['points']` if you want the value to change.

In addition, variables are case sensitive. So in your `if` statement, you should be using lower case `$points`. You can check what `mysql` returns by doing `var_dump($points)`.